# Async Waterfall query not pushed?

Tags: node.js, function, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

so I am using async waterfall as my procedure for passing results of the function to the next. I am currently having a problem with calling a push on the user that resulted from the query.

Here is my code:

```
    exports.contactList = function(req, res) {

    async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {

        Friend.findOne({userId: req.signedCookies.userid}, function(err, users) {
            var friends = [];
            if(err) {throw err};
            for(var i = 0; i < users.friendStatus.length; i++) {
                if(users.friendStatus[i].status === 3) { friends.push(users.friendStatus[i])};  
            }
            //console.log(friends);
            callback(null, friends);
        });


        },

        function(friends, callback) {
            var friendsinfo = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < friends.length; i ++) {
                async.each(friends, function(friend, next) {
                //friendsinfo.push(friend.favorites)


                User.findOne({_id: friend.fuId}, function(err, user) {
                    if (err) { console.log(err); };
                        var object = {'fav': friend.favorites, 'user': user};
                        friendsinfo.push(object);
                        next(err);
                }); 
            }, function(err) {
                console.log('friendsINFO');
                console.log(friendsinfo);
                callback(err, friendsinfo);
            });
            }








        }
    ],

    function(err, results) {
        console.log('RESULTS');
        console.log(results);
        res.render('contactList', {title: 'Weblio', Friends: results});
    });

};
```

Console.log(user) actually prints out the users. the array friendsInfo shows up as undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function (friends, callback) {
var friendsinfo = [];

async.each(friends, function (friend, next) {

    User.findOne({_id: friend.fuId}, function (err, user) {
        friendsinfo.push(user);
        next(err);
    }); 
}, function (err) {
    callback(err, friendsinfo);
});
}
```

Just cleaned up the function from the answer above. Think that is how it should look.

Comment: The problem is that you left out the favorites that need to be added along with the user info.

Comment: Just add friendsinfo.push(friend.favorites); above User.findOne

Comment: yep tried that, but it does not pair up the two correctly, I will add the results in my code

Comment: I think what you should do is create an object and then push that object into the array. var object = { 'favourite' : friend.favorites, 'user' : user};

Comment: Ok that actually worked, but then how do I access the id inside the user part of the object?

Comment: var user = object.user; or object.user.id (I think mongo names id as _id)

Answer (score 2):

You're calling callback() before any User.findOne is done, since they're asynchronous. Use async.each to solve that. **Edit:** Or even better use async.map to create an object (as per @Cam's suggestion).

```
function (friends, callback) {
    async.map(friends, function (friend, next) {
        User.findOne({ _id: friend.fuId }, function (err, user) {
            friendsinfo.push(user);
            next(err, {
                user: user,
                favorites: friend.favorites
            });
        }); 
    }, function (err, friendsinfo) {
        callback(err, friendsinfo);
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is i being called from? If I use async.each

Comment: Also, I want to have favorites pushed along with the user as one object or one sub doc in the array

Comment: @Lion789 I fixed some mistakes in the code and opted to use `async.map()` instead to create an array of objects like @Cam suggested.

Comment: why async map vs each? I only ask because each is working currently?

Comment: Less code :) generally .map is used to convert an array to a new array, in this case an array of friends to an array of users. .each is fine too but you need to keep track of the new array yourself.